# How to manage python3 sys.path on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys.path

I run a cluster of 8 machines (not identical) that all run Ubuntu.  Not always the exact same version, but close.  I'm working on a couple of python modules and am puzzled about sys.path and in general how to best publish the modules so that they are out of the way, but accessable.

I see a number of questions about this, but they are mostly quite old, some are for python2, many seem specific to a different OS. I've tried some answers, but none did any good in my situation.  Some answers I didn't try because I didn't understand them. I'm only interested in python3 on Debian-based Linux (with Fedora a possible outlier).

The bottom line is I cannot seem to change site.path from outside the process I'm starting, but that's what I need to do.

What I've tried:

- Sneaky -- and a solution I really don't like -- is to put my module in one of the directoreis already on the path.  But they are all named some variation on dist-packages and doing it that way just seems wrong.  But it makes the modules accessable.
- Set $PYTHONPATH in the shell before launching python.  No joy.

I'd prefer to have something I can do to a dotfile like .bashrc, and a directory that I can drop my modules into (named site-packages or some such.)  So what can I do to get python3 to recognize and search a site-packages directory?

Comment: Use `pip`. Enter the package's directory and type `pip install .`. Everything will be managed automatically. Your package will be stored in a `site-packages` directory that is already in `sys.path`.

Comment: I'm guessing this means the package has to have a dedicated directory.  Am I right about that?  At the moment, it's a single file that I have in a directory with other stuff.

Comment: Take a look at [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) - download the source `.tar.gz` file and look at the project structure, along with `setup.py`. It's a little complicated, but it's an example of a module that installs as a single `appdirs.py` file in `site-packages`, along with an `appdirs.dist-info` directory that contains all the other stuff. This is just an example, I'd recommend using a `pyproject.toml`-based build system today, but it's definitely possible to just have a single file installed.

Comment: Of course, there's absolutely nothing wrong with having your project install in its own directory, either, even if it is only a single file.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'm puzzled because as near as I can tell there is NOT any site-packages directory on my systems.  Does it get created the first time it's needed?  I worry because it is NOT in sys.path either.

Comment: Yes, it will get created if needed, and will be added to `sys.path`. To create a system-wide `site-packages`, make sure you use `sudo` when running `pip`. Otherwise, it will install in your home directory and only be available to the user that installed it.